# Connect LED-driver (BJT) in circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, led-driver, connect

I need some help in this circuit!

How can I connect LED-driver (BJT) in this circuit? Then what is the valus of **R**B and **R**C  that meet the requirements, so that the LED driver works properly.

Hopefully get help

Online circuit: https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=f5rq8hvpj63d

[image]

Comment: Why have the off source as a  0V cell? wouldn't that just be a ground connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your LED is rated at 20mA, so I'm picking 10mA over the LED as a nice value that works, If you want it for 20mA then the math is all here

The lazy way that this is seeming to ask is to just have the transistor in saturation, acting as a switch, as such lets say its current gain is 100 (beta), we want 10mA or more to flow between collector and emmitor, so we want atleast 100uA to flow in to the base

5V - 0.7V (transistor base) = 4.3V, 
4.3V / 100uA = 43000 ohms (RB), lets pick 39K ohms as the nearest preffered value that is lower

Now with the transistor acting as a switch, we have 5V, while It does not list the LED forward voltage, I'm going to assume 1.5V, as a common value for a red LED (assuming again),

We want 10mA, so..
5V - 1.5V = 3.5V
3.5V / 10mA = 350 Ohms (RC), rounded to nearest preferred value would be 330 ohms

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a question! 
What kind of amplifier this is, and how the transistor β affects RB?

Comment: A NPN transistor is similar to a current amplifier, the base current * the beta = the output current, when the output current is smaller, the transistor C-E junction is "saturated" and will have some small voltage across the 2 pins, e.g. 50mV, it cannot switch on any more,

Comment: A larger beta, means less current needed to saturate the transistor, so a larger resistance value could be used, 10mA / Beta(100) = 100uA

Comment: Hei again @Reroute, I have a question about this Circuit if it possible. Which areas that  that can be used to vary the brightness if needed.

Comment: If you want a higher total brightness, re-run my math for say 20mA, if you then want to reduce it you can vary it with increasign RB from the calculated value.

Comment: Awsome. understood. Thank you for you help.